# Pylance in VS Code raising error in pandas.DataFrame.loc[ , ], but my code runs perfectly fine

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have the pandas latest version installed as of now with python version 3.12.0. While running VS Code, I was running this line of code

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4,4)),
                    index = ['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'],
                    columns = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])

data.loc['Colorado', ['two', 'three']]
```

But Pylance is raising error with the squiggly red underline on the last line of code.

The Error says

> No overloads for "**getitem**" match the provided argumentsPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
> frame.pyi(201, 9): Overload 4 is the closest match
> Argument of type "tuple[Literal['Colorado'], list[str]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "idx" of type "tuple[Scalar, slice]" in function "**getitem**"
> "tuple[Literal['Colorado'], list[str]]" is incompatible with "tuple[Scalar, slice]"
> Tuple entry 2 is incorrect type
> "list[str]" is incompatible with "slice"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

But my code runs absolutely fine when executed. I can use "#type: ignore" to supress the warning but can anyone give me a more permanent solution.

Btw this is my first question in Stack overflow.

Edit: I found out my typecheking was on, so turning that off is a solution but if someone has any better solution please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

While using #type: ignore is a quick workaround, you can provide type hints to make it more explicit. In this case, you can use the Union type to indicate that the index can be either a scalar or a list of strings:

```
from typing import Union

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4)),
                    index=['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'],
                    columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])

# Specify the type of index as Union[Scalar, List[str]]
index_type: Union[str, list[str]] = 'Colorado'
columns_type: Union[str, list[str]] = ['two', 'three']

result = data.loc[index_type, columns_type]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following settings to your `settings.json` in `.vscode` folder:

```
  "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportGeneralTypeIssues": "none",
  },
```